# Parsing logfile with c# and regex

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have a large log file that looks like the 3 row example below.

```
\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex12.log:32:2015-01-04 07:11:22 &actor=%7B%22name%22%3A%5B%22Smith%2C%20Steve%22%5D%2C%22mbox%22%3A%5B%22mailto%3ASmith.Steve%40xyz.com%22%5D%7D&
\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex12.log:32:2015-06-08 02:04:13 &actor=%7B%22name%22%3A%5B%22Brown%2C%20Bob%22%5D%2C%22mbox%22%3A%5B%22mailto%3ABrown.Bob%40xyz.com%22%5D%7D&
\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex12.log:32:2014-08-02 05:50:37 &actor=%7B%22name%22%3A%5B%22Franklin%2C%20Francis%22%5D%2C%22mbox%22%3A%5B%22mailto%3AFranklin.Francis%40xyz.com%22%5D%7D&
```

I need to pull the date, name, and mailto fields that are buried within the log file.

I tried using an online regex generator but only got this far before it seemed to become unwieldy.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //test string
      string txt="\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex12.log:32:2014-08-02 05:50:37 &actor=%7B%22name%22%3A%5B%22Franklin%2C%20Francis%22%5D%2C%22mbox%22%3A%5B%22mailto%3AFranklin.Francis%40xyz.com%22%5D%7D&";

  string re1=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
  string re2="((?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3}))[-:\\/.](?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\\/.](?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1})))(?![\\d])";   // YYYYMMDD 1

  Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
  Match m = r.Match(txt);
  if (m.Success)
  {
        String yyyymmdd1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
        Console.Write("("+yyyymmdd1.ToString()+")"+"\n");
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
}
  }
 }
```

Is there a way to do this in c# with or without regex?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx)? After decoding the string, extraction can be easier.

Comment: How large is your 'large log file'? 50MB? 10GB? 500GB? How many lines of text?

Comment: @JamesBlond largest one is 18MB

Comment: @JamesBlond 65k lines of text

Comment: What tool or library is logging this? Try to get the parser for it. I'm sure there is one.

Comment: @OguzOzgul It's a 3rd party piece of software that writes to the IIS logs. There is no parser available at this time.  Thanks. I tried LogParser 2.2 but it couldn't pick apart the pieces of data I need.

Comment: Try Tx. here is a sample snippet. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/589458d2cc3dcdc390fe it allows you to do Language Integrated Query (LINQ) directly on raw event sources. http://tx.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to split the line into several parts, then decode the url part, get the actor param, deserialize it into an `Actor` and the use it's properties. An quick example would be:

```
string txt = @"\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex12.log:32:2014-08-02 05:50:37 &actor=%7B%22name%22%3A%5B%22Franklin%2C%20Francis%22%5D%2C%22mbox%22%3A%5B%22mailto%3AFranklin.Francis%40xyz.com%22%5D%7D&";

var parts = txt.Split(' ');

var urlParams = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parts[2]);
string actorJson = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(urlParams).Get("actor");
Actor actor = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Actor>(actorJson);

Console.WriteLine(actor.Name + " " + actor.EmailAddress);
```

You would need to add a reference to `System.Web` and `Json.Net` for it to work and of course a definition for your Actor class like:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Actor
    {
        public string[] name { get; set; }
        public string[] mbox { get; set; }

        public string Name { get { return name[0]; } }
        public string EmailAddress { get { return mbox[0].Replace("mailto:", ""); } }
    }
}
```

Now you just get all the lines with the File class and loop through each of them an put all deserilized actors into a List or something similar.

Comment: Just debug it line by line and you will see. It takes only the url parameter part of your log line, then decodes the url (removes all the % characters and so on), then selects the actor parameters value (which is json), deserializes the json value into an instance of an Actor class and that's it. No need for regex.

Comment: Stupid issue, but I'm using .net 4.6 in a console application and I can't access System.Web.  Did you run into this issue? @JamesBlond

Comment: As mentioned above you would need to add a reference to `System.Web` and then put a `using System.Web;` at the top of the file and add the NuGet package `Json.NET` to your project and a using for it as well.

Comment: I went into references > add reference, selected System.Web, but it never shows up in the list.  I'm using VS2015. I'll try in 2013.  Thanks!

Comment: I've done that yesterday in VS2015, no issues. But it might have been a .net 4.52, not 4.6, I don't remember it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95477/discussion-between-999cm999-and-jamesblond).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use a regex and it's in this generalized line form, something like this should work -

`(?m)^\S+:(?<Date>\d+-\d+-\d+)\s(?:(?!&actor=).)+&actor=(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*name(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*(?<LastName>(?:(?!%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|mbox).)+)(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+(?<FirstName>(?:(?!%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|mbox).)*)(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*mbox(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+mailto(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+(?<MailUser>(?:(?!%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}).)+)(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+(?<MailDomain>(?:(?!%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}).)+)(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+&`

It uses the multi-line modifier `(?m)` from a modifier group in the regex.

Formatted:

```
 (?m)
 ^ 
 \S+ 
 :
 (?<Date>                            #_(1 start)         
      \d+ 
      -
      \d+ 
      -
      \d+ 
 )                                   #_(1 end)         
 \s 

 (?:
      (?! &actor= )
      . 
 )+

 &actor=
 (?: % [0-9a-fA-F]{2} )*
 name
 (?: % [0-9a-fA-F]{2} )*

 (?<LastName>                        #_(2 start)         
      (?:
           (?! % [0-9a-fA-F]{2} | mbox )
           . 
      )+
 )                                   #_(2 end)         


 (?: % [0-9a-fA-F]{2} )+

 (?<FirstName>                       #_(3 start)         
      (?:
           (?! % [0-9a-fA-F]{2} | mbox )
           . 
      )*
 )                                   #_(3 end)         

 (?: % [0-9a-fA-F]{2} )*

 mbox
 (?: % [0-9a-fA-F]{2} )+
 mailto


 (?: % [0-9a-fA-F]{2} )+


 (?<MailUser>                        #_(4 start)         
      (?:
           (?! % [0-9a-fA-F]{2} )
           . 
      )+
 )                                   #_(4 end)         

 (?: % [0-9a-fA-F]{2} )+


 (?<MailDomain>                      #_(5 start)         
      (?:
           (?! % [0-9a-fA-F]{2} )
           . 
      )+
 )                                   #_(5 end)         

 (?: % [0-9a-fA-F]{2} )+
 &
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 1 [Date]       -  ( pos 31 , len 10 ) 
2015-01-04  
 **  Grp 2 [LastName]   -  ( pos 80 , len 5 ) 
Smith  
 **  Grp 3 [FirstName]  -  ( pos 91 , len 5 ) 
Steve  
 **  Grp 4 [MailUser]   -  ( pos 133 , len 11 ) 
Smith.Steve  
 **  Grp 5 [MailDomain] -  ( pos 147 , len 7 ) 
xyz.com  

---------------------

 **  Grp 1 [Date]       -  ( pos 197 , len 10 ) 
2015-06-08  
 **  Grp 2 [LastName]   -  ( pos 246 , len 5 ) 
Brown  
 **  Grp 3 [FirstName]  -  ( pos 257 , len 3 ) 
Bob  
 **  Grp 4 [MailUser]   -  ( pos 297 , len 9 ) 
Brown.Bob  
 **  Grp 5 [MailDomain] -  ( pos 309 , len 7 ) 
xyz.com  

----------------------

 **  Grp 1 [Date]       -  ( pos 359 , len 10 ) 
2014-08-02  
 **  Grp 2 [LastName]   -  ( pos 408 , len 8 ) 
Franklin  
 **  Grp 3 [FirstName]  -  ( pos 422 , len 7 ) 
Francis  
 **  Grp 4 [MailUser]   -  ( pos 466 , len 16 ) 
Franklin.Francis  
 **  Grp 5 [MailDomain] -  ( pos 485 , len 7 ) 
xyz.com
```

Also, with a slight modification, you can get them all into a CaptureCollection list
in a single match.

C#

```
string log =
@"
\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex12.log:32:2015-01-04 07:11:22 &actor=%7B%22name%22%3A%5B%22Smith%2C%20Steve%22%5D%2C%22mbox%22%3A%5B%22mailto%3ASmith.Steve%40xyz.com%22%5D%7D&
\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex12.log:32:2015-06-08 02:04:13 &actor=%7B%22name%22%3A%5B%22Brown%2C%20Bob%22%5D%2C%22mbox%22%3A%5B%22mailto%3ABrown.Bob%40xyz.com%22%5D%7D&
\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex12.log:32:2014-08-02 05:50:37 &actor=%7B%22name%22%3A%5B%22Franklin%2C%20Francis%22%5D%2C%22mbox%22%3A%5B%22mailto%3AFranklin.Francis%40xyz.com%22%5D%7D&

sfgbadfbdfbadfbdab
junk .........

\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex12.log:32:2014-08-02 05:50:37 &actor=%7B%22name%22%3A%5B%22Smith%2C%20Joe%22%5D%2C%22mbox%22%3A%5B%22mailto%3ASmith.Joe%40xyz.com%22%5D%7D&
\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex12.log:32:2014-08-02 05:50:37 &actor=%7B%22name%22%3A%5B%22Doe%2C%20Jane%22%5D%2C%22mbox%22%3A%5B%22mailto%3ADoe.Jane%40xyz.com%22%5D%7D&
";

Regex RxLog = new Regex(@"(?m)(?:^\S+:(?<Date>\d+-\d+-\d+)\s(?:(?!&actor=).)+&actor=(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*name(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*(?<LastName>(?:(?!%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|mbox).)+)(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+(?<FirstName>(?:(?!%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|mbox).)*)(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*mbox(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+mailto(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+(?<MailUser>(?:(?!%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}).)+)(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+(?<MailDomain>(?:(?!%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}).)+)(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+&\s*|(?:.*\s))+");

Match logMatch = RxLog.Match(log);
if (logMatch.Success)
{

    CaptureCollection ccDate = logMatch.Groups["Date"].Captures;
    CaptureCollection ccLname = logMatch.Groups["LastName"].Captures;
    CaptureCollection ccFname = logMatch.Groups["FirstName"].Captures;
    CaptureCollection ccUser = logMatch.Groups["MailUser"].Captures;
    CaptureCollection ccDomain = logMatch.Groups["MailDomain"].Captures;

    for (int i = 0; i < ccDate.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}, {2}    {3}@{4}", ccDate[i].Value, ccLname[i].Value, ccFname[i].Value, ccUser[i].Value, ccDomain[i].Value );
}
```

Output:

```
2015-01-04  Smith, Steve    Smith.Steve@xyz.com
2015-06-08  Brown, Bob    Brown.Bob@xyz.com
2014-08-02  Franklin, Francis    Franklin.Francis@xyz.com
2014-08-02  Smith, Joe    Smith.Joe@xyz.com
2014-08-02  Doe, Jane    Doe.Jane@xyz.com
```